# Create new NTFS partition on macbook partition

Tags: partitioning, macbook, osx-leopard

I have 2 partitions on my Macbook:

- C:\ for Windows 7
- D:\ for Mac OS

I don't use MacOS, and I want to install a new Windows 7 64 bit to a new partition.
I hesitate to format `D:\` drive, I don't want to lose my data or access problem.

On Mac OS `D:\` drive there is 85 GB free space.

How can I create a new NTFS partition from this 85 GB Mac OS partition and install Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

> You can easily resize any disk partition in Mac OS X using the
>   included Disk Utility app, located in /Applications/Utilities, and you
>   can even resize a mounted volume. In fact, you can grow or shrink HFS+
>   (Mac OS X) Partitions on the fly, with the resizing done live
>   regardless of whether the drive is internal or an external drive, or
>   even the boot volume.
>
> A word of advice: Resizing mounted boot volumes isn’t always the best
>   idea in the world because there’s a tiny potential something could go
>   wrong. Before you go messing around and resizing your partitions, be
>   sure to backup your data using Time Machine or whatever other backup
>   service you prefer and make a recent back up.
>
> ## Resizing a Mac Drive Partition with Disk Utility
>
> - Open Disk Utility and select the hard drive with partitions you wish to resize
> - Select the “Partition” tab and then click the partition to resize, then click and hold on the little dragging widget in the
>     corner
> - Resize Partition in Mac OS X with Disk Utility
> - Size the partition as you wish, then click “Apply” for the changes to take effect

http://osxdaily.com/2009/11/20/resize-partitions-in-mac-os-x-with-disk-utility/

Comment: Resized boot partition (mounted) without a problem, I think Linux would have complain a bit about